# How to do clipping planes on OpenGL ES 2 or 3?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, clipping, opengl-es-3.0, opengl-es-1.1

On iOS or Android, I have the option to switch to OpenGL ES 2 or 3.
I'm not sure why I would, as I'm not developing a 3D game, but if I were to switch, how would I implement clipping planes? These were allegedly removed in ES 2.

I'd especially like to avoid having to recompile any shader code when a clipping plane's vector changes.

Comment: "I'm not sure why I would, as I'm not developing a 3D game, but if I were to switch, how would I implement clipping planes?" - Sounds like you're 2D. Easiest and most efficient option would be to use the scissor rect if your clipping is screen aligned (you should do this even if you stick with GLES 1.1). Otherwise, doing the clipping yourself on the CPU before issuing verts is probably more efficient than clip planes or equivalents, but is a bit fiddly.

Answer (score 5):

In OpenGL ES you have to use the [**EXT_clip_cull_distance**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_clip_cull_distance.txt) extension.

In the vertex shader you have to set the [`gl_ClipDistance[i]`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Other_inputs) output. `gl_ClipDistance[i]` specifies a clip distance for each user clip plane *i*. Where 0.0 means that the vertex is on the clip plane and > 0.0 means that is it inside the clip plane.

The clipping capabilities has to be enabled.
 e.g.

```
glEnable( CLIP_DISTANCE0_EXT );
```

A vertex shader using `gl_ClipDistance` may look like this, where `u_clipPlane` is the equation for a plane in the form *Ax + By + Cz + D* (imagine this as the normal vector of the plane and the distance to the origin):

```
#extension GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance : enable

precision highp float;

attribute vec3 inPos;   

uniform mat4 u_projectionMat44;
uniform mat4 u_viewMat44;
uniform mat4 u_modelMat44;
uniform vec4 u_clipPlane;

void main()
{   
    vec4 modelPos      = u_modelMat44 * vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
    gl_Position        = u_projectionMat44 * u_viewMat44 * modelPos;
    gl_ClipDistance[0] = dot(modelPos, u_clipPlane);
}
```

See also [Vertex Post-Processing - User-defined clipping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#User-defined_clipping) and [The little Grasshopper - Clip Planes](http://github.prideout.net/clip-planes) tutorial.

---

If the extension is not available, then the clipping can be emulated in the fragment shader, by discarding fragments. See [Fragment Shader - Special operations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations).

See also [OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00 Specification; 6.4 Jumps; page 58](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf):

> The **discard** keyword is only allowed within fragment shaders. It can be used within a fragment shader to abandon the operation on the current fragment. This keyword causes the fragment to be discarded and no updates to any buffers will occur. It would typically be used within a conditional statement, for example:
>
> ```
> if (intensity < 0.0)
>     discard;
> ```

The following WebGL example demonstrates this. Note, the [WebGL 1.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/) context conforms closely to the OpenGL ES 2.0 API.

```js
var readInput = true;
  function changeEventHandler(event){
    readInput = true;
  }
  
  (function loadscene() {
  
  var gl, progDraw, vp_size;
  var bufCube = {};
  var clip = 0.0;
  
  function render(delteMS){

      if ( readInput ) {
          //readInput = false;
          clip = (document.getElementById( "clip" ).value - 50) / 50;
      }

      Camera.create();
      Camera.vp = vp_size;
          
      gl.viewport( 0, 0, vp_size[0], vp_size[1] );
      gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
      gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
      gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

      // set up draw shader
      ShaderProgram.Use( progDraw );
      ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw, "u_projectionMat44", Camera.Perspective() );
      ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw, "u_viewMat44", Camera.LookAt() );
      var modelMat = IdentityMat44()
      modelMat = RotateAxis( modelMat, CalcAng( delteMS, 13.0 ), 0 );
      modelMat = RotateAxis( modelMat, CalcAng( delteMS, 17.0 ), 1 );
      ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw, "u_modelMat44", modelMat );
      ShaderProgram.SetUniformF4( progDraw, "u_clipPlane", [1.0,-1.0,0.0,clip*1.7321] );
      
      // draw scene
      VertexBuffer.Draw( bufCube );

      requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  
  function resize() {
      //vp_size = [gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight];
      vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]
      canvas.width = vp_size[0];
      canvas.height = vp_size[1];
  }
  
  function initScene() {
  
      canvas = document.getElementById( "canvas");
      gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
      //gl = canvas.getContext( "webgl2" );
      if ( !gl )
        return null;
      
      /*
      var ext_frag_depth = gl.getExtension( "EXT_clip_cull_distance" );  // gl_ClipDistance gl_CullDistance
      if (!ext_frag_depth)
          alert('no gl_ClipDistance and gl_CullDistance support');
      */

      progDraw = ShaderProgram.Create( 
        [ { source : "draw-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
          { source : "draw-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
        ] );
      if ( !progDraw.progObj )
          return null;
      progDraw.inPos = ShaderProgram.AttributeIndex( progDraw, "inPos" );
      progDraw.inNV  = ShaderProgram.AttributeIndex( progDraw, "inNV" );
      progDraw.inCol = ShaderProgram.AttributeIndex( progDraw, "inCol" );
      
      // create cube
      var cubePos = [
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0 ];
      var cubeCol = [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ];
      var cubeHlpInx = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 4, 0, 3, 7, 3, 2, 6, 7, 1, 0, 4, 5 ];  
      var cubePosData = [];
      for ( var i = 0; i < cubeHlpInx.length; ++ i ) {
        cubePosData.push( cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3], cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3+1], cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3+2] );
      }
      var cubeNVData = [];
      for ( var i1 = 0; i1 < cubeHlpInx.length; i1 += 4 ) {
      var nv = [0, 0, 0];
      for ( i2 = 0; i2 < 4; ++ i2 ) {
          var i = i1 + i2;
          nv[0] += cubePosData[i*3]; nv[1] += cubePosData[i*3+1]; nv[2] += cubePosData[i*3+2];
      }
      for ( i2 = 0; i2 < 4; ++ i2 )
        cubeNVData.push( nv[0], nv[1], nv[2] );
      }
      var cubeColData = [];
      for ( var is = 0; is < 6; ++ is ) {
        for ( var ip = 0; ip < 4; ++ ip ) {
         cubeColData.push( cubeCol[is*3], cubeCol[is*3+1], cubeCol[is*3+2] ); 
        }
      }
      var cubeInxData = [];
      for ( var i = 0; i < cubeHlpInx.length; i += 4 ) {
        cubeInxData.push( i, i+1, i+2, i, i+2, i+3 );   
      }
      bufCube = VertexBuffer.Create(
      [ { data : cubePosData, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inPos },
        { data : cubeNVData,  attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inNV },
        { data : cubeColData, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inCol } ],
        cubeInxData );
        
      window.onresize = resize;
      resize();
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  
  function Fract( val ) { 
      return val - Math.trunc( val );
  }
  function CalcAng( deltaTime, intervall ) {
      return Fract( deltaTime / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
  }
  function CalcMove( deltaTime, intervall, range ) {
      var pos = self.Fract( deltaTime / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0
      var pos = pos < 1.0 ? pos : (2.0-pos)
      return range[0] + (range[1] - range[0]) * pos;
  }    
  function EllipticalPosition( a, b, angRag ) {
      var a_b = a * a - b * b
      var ea = (a_b <= 0) ? 0 : Math.sqrt( a_b );
      var eb = (a_b >= 0) ? 0 : Math.sqrt( -a_b );
      return [ a * Math.sin( angRag ) - ea, b * Math.cos( angRag ) - eb, 0 ];
  }
  
  glArrayType = typeof Float32Array !="undefined" ? Float32Array : ( typeof WebGLFloatArray != "undefined" ? WebGLFloatArray : Array );
  
  function IdentityMat44() {
    var m = new glArrayType(16);
    m[0]  = 1; m[1]  = 0; m[2]  = 0; m[3]  = 0;
    m[4]  = 0; m[5]  = 1; m[6]  = 0; m[7]  = 0;
    m[8]  = 0; m[9]  = 0; m[10] = 1; m[11] = 0;
    m[12] = 0; m[13] = 0; m[14] = 0; m[15] = 1;
    return m;
  };
  
  function RotateAxis(matA, angRad, axis) {
      var aMap = [ [1, 2], [2, 0], [0, 1] ];
      var a0 = aMap[axis][0], a1 = aMap[axis][1]; 
      var sinAng = Math.sin(angRad), cosAng = Math.cos(angRad);
      var matB = new glArrayType(16);
      for ( var i = 0; i < 16; ++ i ) matB[i] = matA[i];
      for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i ) {
          matB[a0*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * cosAng + matA[a1*4+i] * sinAng;
          matB[a1*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * -sinAng + matA[a1*4+i] * cosAng;
      }
      return matB;
  }
  
  function Cross( a, b ) { return [ a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1], a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2], a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0], 0.0 ]; }
  function Dot( a, b ) { return a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2]; }
  function Normalize( v ) {
      var len = Math.sqrt( v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2] );
      return [ v[0] / len, v[1] / len, v[2] / len ];
  }
  
  var Camera = {};
  Camera.create = function() {
      this.pos    = [0, 3, 0.0];
      this.target = [0, 0, 0];
      this.up     = [0, 0, 1];
      this.fov_y  = 90;
      this.vp     = [800, 600];
      this.near   = 0.5;
      this.far    = 100.0;
  }
  Camera.Perspective = function() {
      var fn = this.far + this.near;
      var f_n = this.far - this.near;
      var r = this.vp[0] / this.vp[1];
      var t = 1 / Math.tan( Math.PI * this.fov_y / 360 );
      var m = IdentityMat44();
      m[0]  = t/r; m[1]  = 0; m[2]  =  0;                              m[3]  = 0;
      m[4]  = 0;   m[5]  = t; m[6]  =  0;                              m[7]  = 0;
      m[8]  = 0;   m[9]  = 0; m[10] = -fn / f_n;                       m[11] = -1;
      m[12] = 0;   m[13] = 0; m[14] = -2 * this.far * this.near / f_n; m[15] =  0;
      return m;
  }
  Camera.LookAt = function() {
      var mz = Normalize( [ this.pos[0]-this.target[0], this.pos[1]-this.target[1], this.pos[2]-this.target[2] ] );
      var mx = Normalize( Cross( this.up, mz ) );
      var my = Normalize( Cross( mz, mx ) );
      var tx = Dot( mx, this.pos );
      var ty = Dot( my, this.pos );
      var tz = Dot( [-mz[0], -mz[1], -mz[2]], this.pos ); 
      var m = IdentityMat44();
      m[0]  = mx[0]; m[1]  = my[0]; m[2]  = mz[0]; m[3]  = 0;
      m[4]  = mx[1]; m[5]  = my[1]; m[6]  = mz[1]; m[7]  = 0;
      m[8]  = mx[2]; m[9]  = my[2]; m[10] = mz[2]; m[11] = 0;
      m[12] = tx;    m[13] = ty;    m[14] = tz;    m[15] = 1; 
      return m;
  } 
  
  var ShaderProgram = {};
  ShaderProgram.Create = function( shaderList ) {
      var shaderObjs = [];
      for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++ i_sh ) {
          var shderObj = this.CompileShader( shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage );
          if ( shderObj == 0 )
              return 0;
          shaderObjs.push( shderObj );
      }
      var prog = {}
      prog.progObj = this.LinkProgram( shaderObjs )
      if ( prog.progObj ) {
          prog.attribIndex = {};
          var noOfAttributes = gl.getProgramParameter( prog.progObj, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES );
          for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfAttributes; ++ i_n ) {
              var name = gl.getActiveAttrib( prog.progObj, i_n ).name;
              prog.attribIndex[name] = gl.getAttribLocation( prog.progObj, name );
          }
          prog.unifomLocation = {};
          var noOfUniforms = gl.getProgramParameter( prog.progObj, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS );
          for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfUniforms; ++ i_n ) {
              var name = gl.getActiveUniform( prog.progObj, i_n ).name;
              prog.unifomLocation[name] = gl.getUniformLocation( prog.progObj, name );
          }
      }
      return prog;
  }
  ShaderProgram.AttributeIndex = function( prog, name ) { return prog.attribIndex[name]; } 
  ShaderProgram.UniformLocation = function( prog, name ) { return prog.unifomLocation[name]; } 
  ShaderProgram.Use = function( prog ) { gl.useProgram( prog.progObj ); } 
  ShaderProgram.SetUniformI1  = function( prog, name, val ) { if(prog.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform1i( prog.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
  ShaderProgram.SetUniformF1  = function( prog, name, val ) { if(prog.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform1f( prog.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
  ShaderProgram.SetUniformF2  = function( prog, name, arr ) { if(prog.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform2fv( prog.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
  ShaderProgram.SetUniformF3  = function( prog, name, arr ) { if(prog.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform3fv( prog.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
  ShaderProgram.SetUniformF4  = function( prog, name, arr ) { if(prog.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform4fv( prog.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
  ShaderProgram.SetUniformM33 = function( prog, name, mat ) { if(prog.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniformMatrix3fv( prog.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
  ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44 = function( prog, name, mat ) { if(prog.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniformMatrix4fv( prog.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
  ShaderProgram.CompileShader = function( source, shaderStage ) {
      var shaderScript = document.getElementById(source);
      if (shaderScript)
        source = shaderScript.text;
      var shaderObj = gl.createShader( shaderStage );
      gl.shaderSource( shaderObj, source );
      gl.compileShader( shaderObj );
      var status = gl.getShaderParameter( shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS );
      if ( !status ) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
      return status ? shaderObj : null;
  } 
  ShaderProgram.LinkProgram = function( shaderObjs ) {
      var prog = gl.createProgram();
      for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++ i_sh )
          gl.attachShader( prog, shaderObjs[i_sh] );
      gl.linkProgram( prog );
      status = gl.getProgramParameter( prog, gl.LINK_STATUS );
      if ( !status ) alert("Could not initialise shaders");
      gl.useProgram( null );
      return status ? prog : null;
  }
  
  var VertexBuffer = {};
  VertexBuffer.Create = function( attributes, indices ) {
      var buffer = {};
      buffer.buf = [];
      buffer.attr = []
      for ( var i = 0; i < attributes.length; ++ i ) {
          buffer.buf.push( gl.createBuffer() );
          buffer.attr.push( { size : attributes[i].attrSize, loc : attributes[i].attrLoc } );
          gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.buf[i] );
          gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( attributes[i].data ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
      }
      buffer.inx = gl.createBuffer();
      gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.inx );
      gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( indices ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
      buffer.inxLen = indices.length;
      gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
      gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
      return buffer;
  }
  VertexBuffer.Draw = function( bufObj ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < bufObj.buf.length; ++ i ) {
          gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.buf[i] );
          gl.vertexAttribPointer( bufObj.attr[i].loc, bufObj.attr[i].size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
          gl.enableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc );
      }
      gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
      gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inxLen, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
      for ( var i = 0; i < bufObj.buf.length; ++ i )
         gl.disableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc );
      gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
      gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
  }
  
  initScene();
  
  })();
```

```css
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#gui {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
}
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    precision highp float;
    
    attribute vec3 inPos;
    attribute vec3 inNV;
    attribute vec3 inCol;
  
    varying vec3  vertPos;
    varying vec3  vertNV;
    varying vec3  vertCol;
    varying float clip_distance;
    
    uniform mat4 u_projectionMat44;
    uniform mat4 u_viewMat44;
    uniform mat4 u_modelMat44;
    uniform vec4 u_clipPlane;
    
    void main()
    {   
        mat4 mv       = u_viewMat44 * u_modelMat44; 
        vertCol       = inCol;
        vertNV        = normalize(mat3(mv) * inNV);
        vec4 viewPos  = mv * vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
        vertPos       = viewPos.xyz;
        gl_Position   = u_projectionMat44 * viewPos;

        vec4 modelPos  = u_modelMat44 * vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
        vec4 clipPlane = vec4(normalize(u_clipPlane.xyz), u_clipPlane.w); 
        clip_distance  = dot(modelPos, clipPlane);
    }
</script>
  
<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec3  vertPos;
    varying vec3  vertNV;
    varying vec3  vertCol;
    varying float clip_distance;
    
    void main()
    {
        if ( clip_distance < 0.0 )
            discard;
        vec3 color   = vertCol;
        gl_FragColor = vec4( color.rgb, 1.0 );
    } 
</script>

<div>
    <form id="gui" name="inputs">
        <table>
            <tr> <td> <font color= #CCF>clipping</font> </td> 
                 <td> <input type="range" id="clip" min="0" max="100" value="50" onchange="changeEventHandler(event);"/></td> </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>


<canvas id="canvas" style="border: none;" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
```